# Different aggregation for dataframe with several columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

I am looking for some short-cut to reduce the manual grouping required:

I have a dataframe with many columns. When grouping the dataframe by 'Level', I want to group two columns using nunique(),but all other columns (ca. 60 columns representing years from 2021 onward) using mean().

Does anyone have an idea how to define 'the rest' of the columns?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'B':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9,10,11,12],'D':[13,14,15,16,17,18],'E':[19,20,21,22,23,24]})
aggdct = dict.fromkeys(df.columns, pd.Series.mean)
del aggdct['X']
aggdct['A'] = pd.Series.nunique
print(df.groupby('X').agg(aggdct))
```

output

```
   A  B   C   D   E
X
1  3  2   8  14  20
2  3  5  11  17  23
```

Explanation: I prepare `dict` with information how to agg using [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) which does provide dict with keys being names of column and values being `pd.Series.mean` functions, then remove column to be used in groupby and changing selected column to hold `pd.Series.nunique` rather than `pd.Series.mean`

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot!